# Change voice in Action

Tags: actions-on-google, ssml

How do I change the voice during my response in "Actions on Google"?  Is there an SSML code to temporarily change the voice, for example, from male to female, while reading a quotation?

Comment: Yes. You got the option to change the voice with SSML. 
Have you saw this: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml you

Comment: Thanks, @IdoGreen. I see the SSML reference, but there is nothing there explaining how to change the voice.

Comment: You can't change the voice at the moment, however you can use SSML to have more customizable (=audio) response. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually can change the voice bye adding a voice tag inside the speak tag. You can try something like this:

```
<speak><voice gender="female">Hello I'm Mary</voice><break time="2s"/><voice gender="male">Hey I'm John</voice><speak>
```

Comment: I've now found that it doesn't seem to have an impact in the Simulator, but does in Google Assistant.

Comment: To update/expand: it appears `<voice gender="male">`, `<voice gender="male" variant="2">`, `<voice gender="female">`, and `<voice gender="female" variant="2">` are all the voices currently supported (though this still doesn't appear to be officially documented anywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the voice at the moment, however you can use Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML), to have more customizable (=audio) response.

For more on how to use SSML with Action On Google: https://medium.com/google-developers/ssml-for-actions-on-google-946117f97fd1

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution for that.

```
const request = {
    // The text to synthesize
    input: { 
      ssml:`<speak version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis
                 http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/synthesis.xsd"
       xml:lang="en-US">   
  <voice gender="female" languages="en-US" required="languages gender variant">It Maria and this is my female voice,</voice>
  <!-- processor-specific voice selection -->
  <voice name="Mike" required="name">Its Mike and its my male voice</voice>
</speak>`
    },

    // The language code and SSML Voice Gender
    voice: { languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL' },

    // The audio encoding type
    audioConfig: { audioEncoding: 'MP3' },
  };
```

That's work for me like a charm